# Solve partial differential equation $F = zp(x+y)+q^2-pq-z^2=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve partial differential equation $$F = zp(x+y)+q^2-pq-z^2=0, p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

### My attempt:

Differentiating partially wrto x,y,z,p,q

$F_x = zp-q \\ F_y=zp , \\F_p = z(x+y) \\ F_q = 2q-p \\ F_z=-2z+px+py \\ \frac{dx}{-F_p}=\frac{dy}{-F_q}=\frac{dz}{-pF_p-qF_q}=\frac{dp}{F_x+pF_z}=\frac{dq}{F_x+qF_z}$

Charpit's equations gives:

$$\frac{dx}{-z(x+y)} = \frac{dy}{p-2q} = \frac{dp}{p^2(x+y)-pz-q} = \frac{dq}{zp-q(p-2q)} = \frac{dz}{(p-2q)q-pz(x+y)} $$

Taking $dx, dy, dz$ terms, i got $$dz=pdx+qdy$$

How to proceed further?

Pls find the detailed calculation part in following image

[image]

Comment: I think that they are several mistakes in your Charpit's equations. Since your calculus is not detailed, one cannot see where is the trouble.

Comment: @JJacquelin can u pls point me where i made mistake?I tried for 3 days and then posted Qn... Pls see the image

Comment: @JJacquelin I am finding it very hard to post in latex. So, i gave my final charpits equations

Comment: @JJacquelin Pls see this problem also --> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873216/solve-partial-differential-equation-by-charpits-equations

Comment: How did you get $F_x=zp-q$ ?. It's too hard for me to read your handwriting. At least can't you write $F_x,F_y,F_p,F_q,F_z$ with LATEX.

Comment: @JJacquelin Pls see now ...

Comment: I don't agree with $F_x$ and  $F_p$ . I suppose that you can correct the Charpit's equations and continue by yourself I will no longer be available.

Comment: Tq, can u pls have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873216/solve-partial-differential-equation-by-charpits-equations

Answer (score 0):

In order to simplify the Lagrange-Charpit equations, let's make the following changes of variables:

1. $z=e^u$; then $(p,q)=(z_x,z_y)=(u_xe^u, u_ye^u)$ and the PDE
   $$
   zp(x+y)+q^2-pq-z^2=0 \tag{1}
   $$
   becomes
   $$
   u_x(x+y)+u_y^2-u_xu_y-1=0. \tag{2}
   $$
2. $u(x,y)=v(\xi,\eta)$, where $(\xi, \eta)=(x+y, x-y)$;
   then $u_x=v_{\xi}\xi_x+v_{\eta}\eta_x=v_{\xi}+v_{\eta}=:P+Q$ and, similarly,
   $u_y=P-Q$. In terms of the new variables, Eq. $(2)$ becomes
   $$
   (P+Q)\xi-2PQ+2Q^2-1=0. \tag{3}
   $$

The Lagrange-Charpit equations for the PDE $(3)$ are
$$
\frac{d\xi}{\xi-2Q}=\frac{d\eta}{\xi-2P+4Q}=\frac{dP}{-P-Q}=\frac{dQ}{0}=\frac{dv}{(P+Q)\xi-4PQ+4Q^2}. \tag{4}
$$
The null denominator in $\frac{dQ}{0}$ implies that $v_{\eta}=Q=a,$
hence $v=a\eta+f(\xi)$ and $P=v_{\xi}=f'(\xi).$

Substituting $P$ and $Q$ in $(3)$, we conclude that $f$ must satisfy the ODE
$$
(f'+a)\xi-2af'+2a^2-1=0 
\implies f'=-a+\frac{1-4a^2}{\xi-2a}, \tag{5}
$$
whose solution is
$$
f(\xi)=-a\xi+(1-4a^2)\ln|\xi-2a|+b. \tag{6}
$$
Therefore,
$$
v(\xi,\eta)=a\eta+f(\xi)=a(\eta-\xi)+(1-4a^2)\ln|\xi-2a|+b 
$$
$$
\implies u(x,y)=-2ay+(1-4a^2)\ln|x+y-2a|+b
$$
$$
\implies z(x,y)=e^u=ce^{-2ay}|x+y-2a|^{1-4a^2} \tag{7}
$$
is a complete integral of the PDE $(1)$.